# iptables rule to submit packets matching a specific negative rule

Tags: linux, iptables

I am using netfilter_queue to pick up certain packets from the kernel and do some processing on them. To, the netfilter queue, I need all packets from a particular source `except UDP packets with src port 2152 & dst port 2152.`

I try to add the iptable rule as

```
iptables -A OUTPUT ! s 192.168.0.3 ! -p udp ! --sport 2905 ! --dport 2905 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

iptables throw up an error of Invalid Argument. Querying dmesg, I see the following error print

```
ip_tables: udp match: only valid for protocol 17
```

I have tried the following variation with the same error thrown.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT ! s 192.168.0.3 ! -p udp --sport 2905 --dport 2905 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

Can you please advise on the correct usage of the iptables command for my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be a lot easier to write your rules if you create a chain, send everything to the chain, and do a RETURN on anything that you don't want the chain to handle.  With a chain you can add other exceptions later without having to come up with a really convoluted rule.

```
iptables -t filter -N out_queue
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -j out_queue
iptables -t filter -A out_queue -p udp --sport 2905 -j RETURN
iptables -t filter -A out_queue -p udp --dport 2905 -j RETURN
iptables -t filter -A out_queue -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

Comment: +1 Nice infos. At the end is exactly what Shorewall does when it creates all the iptables rules.

Comment: Looks like this will work. Let me give it a shot and get back to you. Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the ! be after the options?

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -s ! 192.168.0.3 -p udp --sport ! 2905 --dport ! 2905 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

Comment: `--option ! this` is deprecated in favour of `! --option this`

Comment: Ah...since which version?

Comment: from man iptables:
 -s, --source [!] address[/mask]
 -d, --destination [!] address[/mask]

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.3 -p udp --sport!2905 --dport!2905 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

Comment: if it works, wouldn't it just give me packets from source 192.168.0.3 of proto UDP which do not have src port 2905 & dst port 2905?

I need packets from ANY source barring udp packets from 192.168.0.3 with src port(2905) & dst port(2905)

Comment: Ah sorry...misunderstood.
The shoould be: iptables -A OUTPUT -s!192.168.0.3 -p!udp --sport!2905 --dport!2905 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

Comment: This just does not work. What you suggest is what I tried initially and it gave me the cryptic "only valid for protocol 17" error in dmesg